# Dynamically add or subtract array of children?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am new to React and have been trying to figure out how to control an array of components from a parent component. My job is to create a site where I can add or subtract names to a list, but have gotten stuck on the best way to do it. In this case, I created an array of react components, each with controlled input for title boxes and each with a delete button that would call the parent function's remove function through the prop system. However, I noticed that when doing so, the array in the parent function would remain correct, while the id's of the children components would not change to be reordered, thereby ruining subsequent removals. I am sure I am doing this wrong and would like to find a better and more efficient way of doing this. Thanks!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Music from './music'
import axios from 'axios';

var childrenComponents = [];
class Selection {
constructor(){
    this.music = '';
    this.beginning = 0;
    this.the_end = 0;
}
setTitle=(title)=>{
    this.music = title;
}
setStart=(start)=>{
    this.beginning = start;
}
setEnd=(end)=>{
    this.the_end = end;
}
}

class Practice extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        number_music: 0,
        number: 0,
        selections: Array(0).fill(null),
        deletions: 0,
    }
    this.addAnotherSong = this.addAnotherSong.bind(this);
    this.removeSong = this.removeSong.bind(this);
    this.renderMusicPlayed = this.renderMusicPlayed.bind(this);

}

removeSong(index){
    if((this.state.number_music-1) >= 0){
        alert(index);

        for(var i = 0; i < (this.state.selections.length-1); i++){
            console.log(this.state.selections[i].music);
        }

        childrenComponents.splice(index, 1);


        this.setState({selections: this.state.selections.filter((_, i) => i !== index), 
        number_music: this.state.number_music - 1, 
        deletions: this.state.deletions += 1});

        console.log("========================");
        for(var i = 0; i < (this.state.selections.length-1); i++){
            console.log(this.state.selections[i].music);
        }


        console.log("///////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    }
}
addAnotherSong(){
        this.state.selections.push(new Selection());

        var i = this.state.number_music;


        childrenComponents.push(
            <Music key={i} number={i} subtract={this.removeSong}
                Title={this.state.selections[i].music} Start={this.state.selections[i].beginning}
                End={this.state.selections[i].the_end} changeTitle={this.state.selections[i].setTitle}
                changeStart={this.state.selections[i].changeStart} changeEnd={this.state.selections[i].changeEnd}/>
        );
        this.setState({ number_music: this.state.number_music += 1, number: this.state.number += 1});
}

renderMusicPlayed(){
        return (
            <div>
                {childrenComponents}
            </div>
        );
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=> this.props.practice()}>Log Practice Session</button>
            <h1>{this.props.time}</h1>
            <form >
                    Description: <input type="form" placeholder="How did it go?" name="fname"/><br/>
            </form>

            {this.renderMusicPlayed()}

            <button onClick={()=>this.addAnotherSong()}>Add Another Piece</button>
            {this.state.number_music}
        </div>

    );
}
}

export default Practice;
```

That is the parent.
This is the Child:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import InputBox from './input';
class Music extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: null,
            start: null,
            end: null
        }

    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(props){
        this.setState({ title: this.props.Title});
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <InputBox initialValue={this.props.number} cValue={this.props.Title} identity={this.props.number} updateInput={this.props.changeTitle} />
            <InputBox initialValue="Starting Measure" cValue={this.props.Start} identity={this.props.number} updateInput={this.props.changeStart} />
            <InputBox initialValue="Ending Measure" cValue={this.props.End} identity={this.props.number} updateInput={this.props.changeEnd} />
            <button onClick={()=> this.props.subtract(this.props.number)}>Delete</button>

        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Music;
```

And this is the grand child so to speak:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class InputBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: this.props.initialValue, text: "" }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.updateInput(this.state.value, this.props.identity);
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.cValue}></input>
        )
    }
}
export default InputBox;
```

I guess my main question is what is the ideal way for handling this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your IDs are not changing is because you're pushing  **fully formed**  components to the array.

Imagine we have 3 components - formatting will be a little weird, but hopefully it illustrates the point:

`[ Music: { id: 0 }, Music: { id: 1 }, Music: { id: 2 } ]`

When we click the delete button, say on `Music` with `id: 1`, we end up with this:

`[ Music: { id: 0 }, Music: { id: 2 } ]`

We spliced the right `Music` out, but we now have a wrong index - we never actually changed the `Music` with `id: 2`. It would be much easier (in my opinion) to just  *dynamically*  construct your `Music` components in the `render` function.

Realistically, your `childrenComponents` array isn't all that useful - the `Music` components created in it are all created with the index  **i**  in mind:

```
  Title={this.state.selections[i].music} 
  Start={this.state.selections[i].beginning}
  End={this.state.selections[i].the_end}
```

and so on and so forth.

We could simplify this pretty easily, and consolidate all of this into one array.

Imagine we had an array field `state.children`, which looked something like this:

```
[
    { title: _____, start: _____, end: ____, ... },
    { title: _____, start: _____, end: ____, ... },
    { title: _____, start: _____, end: ____, ... },
]
```

This is a lot more clear in a huge way: our data is consolidated in one, singular place, and we aren't tying them together by some arbitrary index. You've done this in a sense with your `selections` array, but because you are also using `childrenComponents`, you're double managing what is essentially the same data.

We can pretty easily render it, too, with something along the lines of:

```
render() {
    {
        this.state.children.map((child, index) => (
            <Music key={index} 
                   number={index} 
                   subtract={this.removeSong}
                   Title={this.state.children[index].title}
                   ...
             />
        ); 
    }    
}
```

That helps us decouple the actual meat of our objects (title, beginning, ending, etc) from their position in the array, which don't really mean anything and are just getting in the way here. That lets us splice up our array however we see fit, and be certain that we're not breaking any relationships between our components and their indexes.

Comment: Thanks! Getting used to react's state and prop system has been really nonintuitive for me. I appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! As a parting tip, I'd say that I rarely (if ever) create components outside my render functions, and can usually hold every prop my components need in state. In general, React feels really clean if you only work between modifying state, and then figuring out how to render that state. If you feel like you can't do that (and have to use other constructs), it might be time to step back and think about the architecture of your component.

Comment: Actually, now I am running into some other issues. Although the code seems to work most of the time, deleting an element in the array seems to be the only way to force an update on all the children components( which I am trying to control via the parent). Somehow, when I change a part of the object in one of the array elements, nothing seems to update in the text input.

Comment: I have looked into the problem further and found that if I change a state that is not an array, everything works fine. But, as mentioned above, altering the element of an object inside an array does not force an update in the children. I also have used shouldComponentUpdate, which will not recognize changes in props if they are only made to the array of selections(in this example). Should I make a new question to get this solved? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does shouldComponentUpdate look like, and what component have you put it in? It doesn't sound like you're using it correctly.

Comment: well, I know I am not using shouldComponentUpdate correctly, but I experimented with it while trying to figure out why updating a variable in the object in the element of the state array would not update the props sent to the children.

Comment: Noticed you put up a new question, gonna head over there and look into it a little bit.

Comment: yeah. I just thought the issue changed from architecture to more like a weird kinda glitch, so. Hope that is okay

Comment: I'm pretty new to stack overflow as well so I'm not 100% sure, but it's definitely a different issue and I'm currently writing up an answer so I think it'll be fine.